# Workflow communication between two websites Sharepoin 2010

Tags: workflow

Good morning.

Is there a possibility to let two lists communicate when they are on two different websites but on the same server?
The only solution were Nintex or progamming an EventReceiver.
Is there any other option for me?

Thanks for answering!

Best regards
Jonathan

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "communicate" ? What is that you need to do? please, more context! :(

Comment: I send a listobject from one list to another. The other list is placed in another website.

Comment: what's a listobject ? And what does "I send" mean? When, how, ...

Comment: I mean for example a document in a library. It is supposed to be sent when it is added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With OOTB workflows, you cannot copy or move items cross-site.
You have a couple of options:

- events receivers (as you already said)
- the SharePoint JSOM ([javascript object model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185006%28v=office.14%29.aspx))
- custom SharePoint Designer workflow activities ([on codeplex](http://spdactivities.codeplex.com/)). They have a Copy List Item Extended Activity which does exactly what you need